# How to add a subview to a tableview only covering the table cell but not the table header view

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, subview

I'm using a UISegmentedControl as the headerview of a tableview. Now I want to add loading view (a view defined by myself) only covering the table cells but not my headerview. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this view to the cell you want:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathOfCell];
[cell addSubview:view];
```

Comment: You didn't get my point. If doing like what you say, every cell will show the same loading view, which will also affect the original display.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to add the loading view would be like this

```
// get the frame of your table header view
CGRect headerFrame = headerView.frame;

// construct a frame that is the screen minus the space for your header
CGRect loadingFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
loadingFrame.origin.y += headerFrame.size.height;
loadingFrame.size.height -= headerFrame.size.height;

// use that frame to create your loading view
MyLoadingView *loadingView = [[MyLoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:loadingFrame];

// add your view to the window *
[[headerView window] addSubview:loadingView];
```

* Adding the view to the window may not be the best thing for your design, but since I don't know any of the details of your view hierarchy, this is the way that will always work.

*Caution: If you do not cover up the segmented control, and it is enabled, the user may click on it and change the state of the app when you aren't expecting it - like when you're trying to load something for them.  Be sure that you can cancel this loading view if the user changes the state of the app.*

Comment: my view is a uitableview and there is a navigation bar on top. Can you fix it for my view hierachy.

Comment: that isn't really the level of detail I was talking about :)  I'm pretty sure that if you try substituting some views of your own in place of `[headerView window]` you'll be able to figure it out pretty quick.